# Creating symlink gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, drupal-7, symlink

Applied cmd: `ln -s subdir`
Edits to .htaccess: added this chunk between `RewriteBase /` and first `RewriteCond` line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir
RewriteRule ^ subdir/index.php [L]
```

Loading the page (path e.g. www.example.com/subdir) gives 500 Internal Server Error. The log gives: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` But I don't get it at all, where is it pulling that 10 redirects from?

The website is www.example.com and is running in one db (on Drupal). You can have multisites while running on same root install of CMS and database (but with prefixes). So the new website should open when visiting www.example.com/subdir (its FTP dir is htdocs/sites/example.com.recruiting) More infos: https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site#subdirectory, but like I mentioned before, applying the .htaccess part ends up in internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions should mean `rewrite if not already /subdir` but it is doing reverse.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subdir|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^ subdir/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Now it loads the old site which is in root dir with page not found message. It should load that new multisite subdir (Drupal https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) Also I got kicked out from Drupal answers website saying it's not related, so you are my last hope.

Comment: Well you didn't mention about Drupal before and my answer was specifically targeted at the problem you described i.e. 500 error and I believe this answer takes care of that. It is better to create a new question for the Drupal question after accepting this answer.

Comment: Sorry I am not a Drupal expert so I cannot answer Drupal specific questions. I wouldn't have answered if question had Drupal mentioned earlier.

Comment: I didn't mention it was Drupal because I was spammed that this is not Drupal related in drupal.stackexchange, so I do not know where to post my question anymore.

Comment: I can only resolve rewrite issue and this answer does resolve your 500 error. Beyond that I don't know how to make multisite working in Drupal.